# Transfer string from C# app to OPEN Excel 2003 worksheet cell

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, excel-2003

I need to transfer a string from C# app into **already opened** Excel worksheet. I think automation or RDI should be able to do so but dont know how..

As a variation, instead of copying it into a cell - launch a VBA macro / sub with the string as a parameter (if it is easier)...

Please help.

.NET 3.5 / Excel 2003

*P.S. Not through clipboard - the transfer must be without user intervention.*

Comment: Note that copying through the clipboard does not require user intervention. That still doesn't make it the best route to take, though.

Comment: please tell how you notify opened excel file that the data is ready in the clipboard? i'd like to hear that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I have resolved this:

```
Workbook = (Excel.Workbook)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(FileName);
```

the above code helps to find opened file amongst several instances of Excel and amongst opened files with each instance.

The writing to the cell is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

For an Excel._Workbook oWS, you can write it like this:

```
            // Row 1
            int nR = 1;
            int nC = 1 ;
            oWS.Cells[nR,nC] = "DIVISION" ;
```

Comment: challenge was to find the opened file not to change cell value. thanks